# Why am I getting connection refused?

Tags: bash, perl

I am transferring files over sftp. Both my bash and Perl script are not able to connect.

I am able to connect to the remote server with psftp and copy files, but the idea is to be able to automate.

Following advice on SO posts I have installed ssh and sshd on my local machine. However on the remote server there is no .ssh directory, so I could not copy the id_dsa.pub file there.
My bash script below

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="rema"
HOSTS="aa.bb.ccc.ddd"
PASSWORD="rema"
SCRIPT="cd data; pwd; cp gateway_data* /home/meteo/AWS_Data/Data"
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} ${PASSWORD} ${SCRIPT}
```

I need correction if this is the correct way of copying all files gateway_data to a local PC, but that is not the current problem.

The script keeps asking for password and on the third attempt stop with (publickey,password)

```
rema@meteo's password: 

Permission denied, please try again.
rema@meteo's password: 

Permission denied, please try again.

rema@meteo's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

My perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
  use  Net::FTP;

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use POSIX qw{strftime};
  use File::Path;
  use File::Copy;
  my $debug = 0;

  my $User = 'rema';
  my $Pass = 'rema';
  my $host = 'aa.bb.ccc.ddd';

  my $remote_basedir = '/';
  my $local_basedir = '../Data';
  my $remote_datadir ='data';

  my $yr = strftime "%Y", localtime();
  my $hr = strftime "%H", localtime();
  my $dat = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime();

  my $localdir= "$local_basedir/$dat$hr";
   if(! -d $localdir) {
    print "mkpath $localdir\n" if $debug;
    mkpath ($localdir) or die "mkpath '$localdir' failed: $! ($^E)";
}

# Setup to do the ftp
  print "Connecting to $host ...\n";
  my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) or die "Error connecting to $host: $!";
  $ftp->setcwd($remote_datadir) or die "unable to change cwd: " . $ftp->error;

# retrieve data
  print "Copying data\n";
  $ftp->cwd($remote_datadir);

  print "Retrieving files from $remote_datadir to $localdir\n";
  my @files = $ftp->ls;
  foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if -d $file;
    next unless $file =~ /^gateway_data/;
    print $file;

    print "Getting $file\n" if $debug;
    $ftp->get($file) or warn "Failed '$file': $! ($^E)";
    }

  $ftp->close;
  print "copying ends\n";
  exit 0;
```

This gives "Connection refused at ./AWS_ftptransf_rema.pl line 44."

A copy of this script is put on the remote machine to send files to the local machine. That script does not give any error. It actually lists the files to be copied but does nothing. Here is a code snippet from this third script, after making connection

```
  opendir(DIR, './');
  my @files=readdir(DIR);
  foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if -d $file;
    next unless $file =~ /^gateway_data/;
    $ftp->put($file) or warn "Failed '$file': $! ($^E)";
#    $ftp->send($file) or warn "Failed '$file': $! ($^E)";
}
```

Both put and send do the same thing, i.e. notihng
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols. You can not access a SFTP server using Net::FTP!

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` isn't a perl error message, it's an OS error message. It means literally, that there was nothing listening on the port you tried to connect to.

I think the core of your problem might be that you're trying to ssh with one script and FTP with the other. That's just not going to work.

Can I suggest rather than scripting it you might want to take a look at `rsync` which is a system designed for synchronising directories between two different systems?

Other than that:

- your first problem is that `ssh` will not accept inline passwords. You NEED to get your ssh public/private key auth sorted to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, which confirm what I was fearing that it is an OS problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. Check whether _ftp_ is enabled - it probably isn't.

Comment: as a matter of fact I have tried an rsync one liner, it gives the same, permission denied. Moreover rsync seems to be soley interactive (I have to read more), the goal is to automate. I am also looking at using Net::SSH::Perl

Answer (score -1):

Connection refused : Thats thrown by underlying Kernel. One of the reason could be firewall might be blocking the incoming connections. Default policy of input might have set to drop. As ssh uses port 22,  you need to explicitly open the port using

ufw allow 22/tcp

Ufw is uncomplicated firewall.

Even if firewall allows traffic distined to a particular port, you need a service to be run on that port. 
For instance say 
You have opened port 7777 using ufw allow 7777/tcp and then scan the system using
echo > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/7777 you get bash connection refused.
It literally not able to send packets to your own loop back interface. 
However echo> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80 does work. It is because there is a service running behind the port 80.
In above case, even you tell firewall to accept incoming connection,  there is no service running on the port 7777.
So what you could is run a service like netcat or in my case I wrote a python code to accept the connection to port 7777.
I have also tried to code in c programming. Everything you required is socket programming.  In your case that could be a pearl script.